# How do I output answer of my user input knowledge base in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I've made this code for prolog that asks you about some features of a climate. its supposed to read these into the knowledge base and then output what the climate with all these features is called.

But right now it just outputs a random number. If you remove the last 5 lines and end it there, you can manually output the expected answer by typing in a new line in the shell, typing  climate(X).

I'm using SWI-prolog (AMD64, Multi-threaded, version 8.0.2)

```
climate(dry) :-
    temp(high),
    humidity(dry),
    falling(none).
climate(polar) :-
    temp(low),
    humidity(dry),
    falling(snow).
climate(tropical) :-
    temp(mid),
    humidity(wet),
    falling(rain).
climate(midlat):-
    temp(mid),
    humidity(damp);
    falling(rain).
start :-
    write("Is temperature low, mid or high?: "),
    read(Temp), nl,
    write("Is humidity dry, damp or wet?: "),
    read(Humid), nl,
    write("Does none, rain or snow fall regularly?: "),
    read(Fall), nl,
    assert(temp(Temp)),
    assert(humidity(Humid)),
    assert(falling(Fall)),
    write("The climate is: "),
    write(climate(Climate)), /*Here Is where it screws up*/
    retractall(temp(_)),
    retractall(humidity(_)),
    retractall(falling(_)).
```

If you input, 'low' then 'dry' then 'snow'; it should output "The climate is: polar"

but right now its outputting; "The climate is: climate(_8808)". the number in climate() is always changing.

Comment: You don't have functions in Prolog, just relations. Change `write(climate(Climate)),` to `climate(Climate),write(Climate),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CapelliC said, instead of `write(climate(Climate))` use `climate(Climate), write(Climate)`. The former tells Prolog interpreter to write a compound term `climate` with an unbound variable `Climate`, which results in an nondeterministic number preceded by an underscore being written. The latter, however, tells Prolog that the body of the rule `start` can be satisfied iff it can substitute a variable `Climate` in the whole body such that all subgoals can be satisfied using this substitution. As `write(_)` will always succeed, it suffices to match `Climate` to one of the climates you provided earlier.